# Is there any way to hint or annotate VB.NET names in order to disambiguate case collisions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr

We have a .NET assembly providing an API that's happily been in use in C# and other .NET languages for years. Unfortunately, that API is constructed such that there are "collisions" as far as VB.NET is concerned, due to its [case insensitivity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235408%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). In particular, the collisions are between namespaces (e.g. `com.foo.bar`) and classes (e.g. `com.foo.Bar`).

Is there any annotation, hint, or attribute I can add to names used in `Imports` (and elsewhere) that would allow me to disambiguate that e.g. *this* name is a namespace, and *that* name is a class? Without something like this, it seems our only option will be to generate a separate VB-only assembly with a rewritten API…

Comment: `Imports XYZ = com.foo.bar` as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix This does not appear to work. `Imports XXX = com.foo.bar` yields the same `'bar' is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in namespace 'com.foo'` error. My understanding is that the `Imports XYZ = ...` syntax is only useful for disambiguating same-named namespaces available from different assemblies?

Comment: from that, it doesnt sound like `com.foo.bar` is actually a Namespace, the bar part is a Type.  If there is also a different `Bar` type in the same Namespace you might be out of luck.  There is a data provider library (I thought it was MySql) where there is a `Date` and a `date` DbType

Comment: Nope, it's definitely a namespace as well; it contains a variety of other classes and further namespaces, too (`com.foo.bar.baz`, and so on). All of this works without a hitch in C# and F#. I'd like to avoid having a special build for people that use VB. But yeah, I'm not hopeful. :-/

Answer (score -1):

And if you utilize FULLY QUALIFIED reference?
SOmething like:

```
Imports XYZ = MyDll.com.foo.Bar     ' First DLL namespace
Imports com.foo.bar                 ' Other DLL namespace
```

Comment: The "conflicting" names are all coming from a single DLL (e.g. a namespace like `com.foo.bar`, and a class `Bar` in namespace `com.foo`).

Comment: Hmmm... Since all namespaces are case insensitive, I believe that both residing in same DLL is really a problem. Anyway, I believe you have ONLY two options:  1) try to recompile via source (unpractical in your environment)   2) Try to rename via DLL direct-access, I mean, try an HexEditor and see if you can locate these names inside the library and try to rename one of them. I know, it´s an emergency procedure, may function or not.